# How to show a popup after the contact form 7 succesfully submitted

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, plugins

I have applied contact form 7 plugin to my static page. Normally after customer submit the button, confirmation message will appear under the submit button. I want to display confirmation message in pop up window. how can I do that.

contact form 7

Thank you for your message. It has been sent.

Answer (score 1):

You would be using one of the DOM events in JS:

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
  // Open pop up here
}, false );
```

Check the `event.detail` properties for information on the form successfully  submitted.

[Documentation](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/)

Comment: Thank you very much for response. I am a beginner and can you please explain or provide a sample code. It will be great help to me.

Comment: What's wrong with the sample code I've already provided?